# Ubuntu 16.04 froze and crashed on install

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I just tried to upgrade to 16.04 and it froze during install.  Wasnt sure what to do, couldnt get anything to respond so I cancelled and tried to restart.  Now I get a list of 6 "OK"s:

```
Created slice system-getty.slice
Started network time synchronization
Reached target System time Synchronization
Started LSB: App Armor initialization.
Started udev Kernel Device manager
Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Reached target printer.
```

A cursor is flashing but I cant type anything.  However if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> it tries to boot and I have access to <kbd>F9</kbd> <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>

I'm pretty unfamiliar with Ubuntu.  Any help is appreciated.  I couldn't find answers to this specific issue on the forum.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Nick Weinberg.  Any suggestions on how I can get an answer to this problem? I'm unable to use my computer... would be great to fix this, don't know where to begin.  I've searched the whole forum and couldn't find an answer... must be a series of commands or something to install 16.04 from this state? Or to go back to 14.0?  I wonder if I've lost everything... thanks for any help.